# Karma runs the wrong reporter

Tags: karma-runner

Running the following gives me output from a TeamCity reporter even though the Karma.config.js states 'progress' and the command line switch is 'progress'. I don't even have the TeamCity report install locally or globally?! Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

```
C:\Projects\Project>karma run --reporters progress
##teamcity[enteredTheMatrix]
##teamcity[testSuiteStarted nodeId='1' parentNodeId='0' name='karma.conf.js' nodeType='config' locationHint='config://C:\Projects\Project\tests\karma.conf.js']
##teamcity[testSuiteStarted nodeId='2' parentNodeId='1' name='Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 7 0.0.0)' nodeType='browser']
##teamcity[testCount count='2']
##teamcity[testSuiteStarted nodeId='3' parentNodeId='2' name='Simple test' nodeType='suite' locationHint='suite://Simple test']
##teamcity[testStarted nodeId='4' parentNodeId='3' name='should pass' nodeType='test' locationHint='test://Simple test.should pass']
##teamcity[testStdOut nodeId='4' out='|'/base/tests/results/unit/viewModelSpec.js|'|n']
##teamcity[testFinished nodeId='4' duration='0']
##teamcity[testSuiteStarted nodeId='5' parentNodeId='2' name='Results Page View Model' nodeType='suite' locationHint='suite://Results Page View Model']
##teamcity[testSuiteStarted nodeId='6' parentNodeId='5' name='convertDate function' nodeType='suite' locationHint='suite://Results Page View Model.convertDate function']
##teamcity[testStarted nodeId='7' parentNodeId='6' name='should return a string |'loading...|' when the date has yet to be set' nodeType='test' locationHint='test://Results Page View Model.convertDate function.should return a string |'loading\.\.\.|' when the date has yet to be set']
##teamcity[testFinished nodeId='7' duration='0']
##teamcity[testSuiteFinished nodeId='3']
##teamcity[testSuiteFinished nodeId='6']
##teamcity[testSuiteFinished nodeId='5']
##teamcity[testSuiteFinished nodeId='2']
##teamcity[testSuiteFinished nodeId='1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this mystery out myself. If you have spawned a Karma server through Intelij\Webstorm etc. then the server is configured with the TeamCity reporter. Spawn your own server and you get the reporter you specified. :)